# PerformancePoint - Any negative impact to turning on this feature?

Tags: performancepoint

Is there any issue with PerfomancePoint?  My SCA will not turn on PerformancePoint in PROD SharePoint 2013.  He will only turn on PerformancePoint in a Sandbox environment that no one is really using. Any information on how I can get the Sandbox environment to test it or justify turning on in Prod? Are there other tools (MsAccess) that generate the Business intelligence reporting capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

There should be little to no impact in turning PerformancePoint on, the difficulty arises when you try to use it afterwards :)

With PerformancePoint, there is the possibility that without proper governance and controls, large volumes of data and large complex reports could be added. This could effect either disk space on your servers, or processing large reports could slow down everyone else's usage.

There are controls that can help mitigate this, and typically when you are adding PerformancePoint to an existing SharePoint you can add additional application servers to run the service, reducing the impact on the Web Front End (WFE) servers or other application severs being used for general SharePoint use.

By sandbox environment, I think your SCA is recommending setting up a separate SharePoint instance on different servers entirely. This would be very useful, as it would allow you to enable PerformancePoint, set up some realistic usage scenarios and do capacity planning based on that which could support your request to enable it in the production environment. Or, it could become your production PerformancePoint environment.

For other tools, you should really consider looking at [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/), Microsoft's Cloud based replacement for PerformancePoint and PowerPivot. There is a free light version which you can use to try it out, and if you need increased capacity then you can consider purchasing licenses at that point. And because it's a cloud based service you don't need to worry too much about servers and infrastructure.